# Trying to solve Lowest common ancestor

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

[image: question is posted in image below]

```
var lowestCommonAncestor = function(root, p, q) {
  // return the path to the node
  let path = []
  const search = (node, target) => {
    if (node === null) return false
    
    path.push(node)
    
    if (node === target) return true
    
    const leftSearched = search(node.left, target)
    
    if (leftSearched) return true
    
    const rightSearched = search(node.right,target)
    
    if (rightSearched) return true
    
    path.pop()
  }
  
  search(root, p)
  const pathP = path
  path = []
  search(root, q)
  const pathQ = path
  
  let result
  while(pathP.length > 0 && pathQ.length > 0 && pathP[0] === pathQ[0]) {
    result = pathP[0]
    pathP.shift()
    pathQ.shift()
  }

  return result
};


console.log(lowestCommonAncestor([3,5,1,6,2,0,8,null,null,7,4],5,1));
```

Iam getting following error message
**const leftSearched = search(node.left, target)
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined**

Could someone help me to fix this issue

Comment: `node` is an Array. I’m really not sure why you expect `node.left` or `node.right` to exist. Isn’t this supposed to be some kind of tree structure? Where do you attempt to convert the Array to this tree structure?

Comment: Console.log it out... You need to debug a little. I can tell you node is undefined and you want to access property 'left' of it.

Comment: @SebastianSimon 
I have posted the question in the image for reference

Comment: @suriyan Converting the array to a binary tree is part of the task. You haven’t done that yet.

Comment: @SebastianSimon , as part of solution they have given this 
function TreeNode(val) {
     this.val = val;
       this.left = this.right = null;
   }
But i dont know how to convert array to Binary tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leet Code, as some other code challenge sites, will transform the array input (actually the *text* input having JSON notation) into an instance of `TreeNode`, and will pass *that* as argument to the function with your solution code.

When you want to run the solution locally, you'll have to take care of this transformation yourself. For that purpose you could make use of the `fromList` function -- specifically for binary trees.

NB: you have a bug in your `search` function. `if (node === target)` should be `if (node.val === target)`.

```js
// LeetCode template:
function TreeNode(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.left = this.right = null;
}

// Tool to convert array input to a tree: 
function fromList(values) {
    if (!values) return;

    let it = (function* () {
        for (let value of values) {
            yield value == null ? null : new TreeNode(value);
        }
        while (true) yield null;
    })();
        
    let root = it.next().value;
    let nextlevel = [root];
    while (nextlevel.length) {
        let level = nextlevel;
        nextlevel = [];
        for (let node of level) {
            if (node) {
                node.left = it.next().value;
                node.right = it.next().value;
                nextlevel.push(node.left, node.right);
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}

// Your function
var lowestCommonAncestor = function(root, p, q) {
  // return the path to the node
  let path = []
  const search = (node, target) => {
    if (node === null) return false;
    path.push(node);
    if (node.val === target) return true;
    const leftSearched = search(node.left, target);
    if (leftSearched) return true;
    const rightSearched = search(node.right,target);
    if (rightSearched) return true;
    path.pop();
  }
  
  search(root, p);
  const pathP = path;
  path = [];
  search(root, q);
  const pathQ = path;
  
  let result;
  while(pathP.length > 0 && pathQ.length > 0 && pathP[0] === pathQ[0]) {
    result = pathP[0];
    pathP.shift();
    pathQ.shift();
  }

  return result;
};

// Running your solution on some input
let input = [3,5,1,6,2,0,8,null,null,7,4];
// Make the conversion that LeetCode would do
let root = fromList(input);
let lca = lowestCommonAncestor(root,5,1);
// For your own purposes, just print the value of that node:
console.log(lca.val); // 3
```

Comment: Many thanks for your solution , this is what exactly i was looking for.